# Linux(CentOS) の man ページを、段落内のみ改行せずテキスト出力するには？

Tags: linux, centos, shellscript, sh

**普通にテキスト出力した場合**

```
書式
       man  [-adfhktwW] [-m system] [-p string] [-C config_file] [-M path] [-P
       pager] [-S section_list] [section] name ...

説明
       man はオンライン・マニュアル・ページを整形し表示する。このバージョン の
       man コマンドでは環境変数 MANPATH と (MAN)PAGER を設定できる。これにより
       、個人的なマニュアルページを設定したり、整形したページを表示するプロ グ
```

---

**下記形式でデキスト出力するには？**
・段落内のみ改行しない

```
書式
       man  [-adfhktwW] [-m system] [-p string] [-C config_file] [-M path] [-Ppager] [-S section_list] [section] name ...

説明
       man はオンライン・マニュアル・ページを整形し表示する。このバージョン の man コマンドでは環境変数 MANPATH と (MAN)PAGER を設定できる。これにより、個人的なマニュアルページを設定したり、整形したページを表示するプロ グ
```

Comment: どのような目的でしょうか。たとえば、プログラムでパースしやすくする目的であれば、`zcat /usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz | groff -mandoc -Thtml` のようにいったんHTMLにすることができます。

Comment: HTMLに出来るのですね。(そんなことが出来るとは思っていなかったので質問しなかったのですが、)大変参考になりました

Answer (score 3, accepted):

不完全だけど、こうするとか。1段落が数 GB あることはないでしょうから、まず問題ないでしょう。

```
$ MANWIDTH=`getconf INT_MAX` man man
```